# html text mask pattern (a****a) like citicards.com

Tags: javascript, html

How does citicards.com implement the login ID text box with special mask?

When you type "johndoe" and focus out the textbox becomes "jo***oe"

Is there a HTML5 mask with pattern?

[image]

Comment: The closest HTML way, to my knowledge, is a password field (and that's all asterisks).

Comment: You can create new element that do this, or use javascript

Comment: I've created a simple implementation of it using javascript @user3658423

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a sample implementation of the desired behaviour using pure javascript. This is just for a sample. You may need to do length check etc before actually using `substr`

```js
  
document.querySelector("input#accountName").addEventListener("blur", function() {
  var value = this.value;
  document.querySelector("#maskedAccountName").textContent=this.value.substr(0,2)+this.value.substr(2,value.length-2).replace(/./g,"*")+this.value.substr(this.value.length-2, this.value.length);
this.style.display = "none";
document.querySelector("#maskedAccountName").style.display = "block";
}, false);

document.querySelector("#maskedAccountName").addEventListener("click", function() {
   this.style.display = "none";
   document.querySelector("input#accountName").style.display = "block";
   document.querySelector("input#accountName").focus();
}, false);
```

```css
div#maskedAccountName {
  border: 1px solid rgba(231, 231, 231, 0.67);
  padding: 2px;
  display: none;
  border-top-style: inset;
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
  background-color: white;
  width: 120px;

}
```

```html
  <input type="text" id="accountName">
  
  <div id="maskedAccountName">

  </div>
```

The reason why I'm not changing the existing `input` value is I may not be able to read the original value when accessed inside the form submit. So i've created a hidden div which is shown in place of the original input element. You can style the `div` to be same as the input element using CSS.

Comment: thank you...some fixes and I got what citicards.com does...very good solution

Answer (score 1):

You have to use JS/jQuery. First count how mush letters from start and end you wish to take off, then replace everything else with `*` and append to fake input field.

You can see that in action here (replace `opacity` to 0 to completely hide input field, `display: none` will not work here, because you have to click on input itself):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#hField").focusin(
    function() {
      $('#hFieldSp').text($(this).val());
    });
  $("#hField").focusout(function() {
    var start = '';
    var end = '';
    var value = $(this).val();
    var stars = '';

    if (value.length < 3) {
      return;
    }

    if (value.length > 6) {
      start = value.substring(0, 2);
      end = value.substring(value.length - 2);
      stars = '*'.repeat(Math.max(1, value.length - 4));
    } else {
      start = value.substring(0, 1);
      end = value.substring(value.length - 1);
      stars = '*'.repeat(Math.max(1, value.length - 2));
    }

    $('#hFieldSp').text(start + stars + end);
  });

  $(document).on('input paste change', '#hField', function() {
    $('#hFieldSp').text($(this).val());
  });
});

String.prototype.repeat = function(num) {
  return new Array(num + 1).join(this);
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
#hField,
#hFieldSp {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
#hField {
  opacity: .2;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="hFieldSp"></div>
  <input type="text" id="hField" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a dummy input for the display. Then on blur, transfer the value to a hidden input and alter the text in the dummy. You might also want the reverse in place in case the user wants to alter the value: on focus, copy the value from the hidden input to the dummy. Here's a sample, no jQuery required, and if there are less than 5 characters in the input, it will make all *s instead.

```js
    var start = 0;
    var end = 4;
    var dummy_user = document.getElementById("user");
    var actual_user = document.getElementById("hidden_user");
    dummy_user.addEventListener("blur", function() {
        actual_user.value = dummy_user.value;
        if (dummy_user.value.length > 4) {
            start = 2;
            end = dummy_user.value.length - 2;
        }
        var val = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < start; i++) {
            val += dummy_user.value[i];
        }
        for (i = start; i < end; i++) {
            val += "*";
        }
        for (i = end; i < dummy_user.value.length; i++) {
            val += dummy_user.value[i];
        }
        dummy_user.value = val;
    });
    dummy_user.addEventListener("focus", function() {
        this.value = actual_user.value;
    });
```

```html
    <form action="">
        <input type="text" name="user" id="user">
        <input type="hidden" name="hidden_user" id="hidden_user" value="">
        <input type="password" name="password">
        <input type="submit" value="Sign in">
    </form>
```